# convert java's xml Element object to text

Tags: java, xml, dom, w3c

how to convert org.w3c.dom.Element object to text

example:

from:

```
Element e= doc.createElement("element");
e.setAttribute("x", "10");
```

need function to transform to :

result text :

```
<element x="10"/>
```

or:

```
<element x="10"></element>
```

Comment: Does the Element instance have a toXml() or toString() method? If yes, does those methods produce the XML?

Comment: it has the toString inherited from the object  class and no toXml method

Comment: Ok...but the toString() method does not produce the desired XML I assume?

Comment: it doesn't , nvm anyways i just finished writing my own class to do the job, ty anyway

Comment: @user882611 - If you've written your own class, why not post it here so others may find help in the future?

Answer (score 1):

Using only the standard API, this works:

```
Element element = ...

StringWriter buffer = new StringWriter();
TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer().transform(
    new DOMSource(element), new StreamResult(buffer)
);

String xml = buffer.toString();
```

Not pretty, but avoids using proprietary APIs.